# Jquery executar um atalho

Tags: jquery

Preciso executar este atalho de minimizar a tela:

<kbd>Alt+shift+n</kbd>

Há alguma forma de executar isso após um *click* no botão?

```
$("#btnVoltar").click(function(){
    var ALT =   18;
    var space = 32;
    var n = 78;
.....
```

Comment: Que questão interessante, visto que não existe nenhuma forma de minimizar a tela com javascript, fiz um questionamento parecido na comunidade principal, assim que eu obtiver a resposta te dou um feedback

Comment: Opa valeu mano, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O Ricardo postou uma solução,vou chegar em casa e testar , se ser certo, já te mando também

Answer (score -1):

Esse código faz isso:

```
var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.which = 78;  // tecla n
press.shiftKey = true;  // shift pressionado
press.altKey = true;  // alt pressionado
$("algumElemento").trigger(press);  // aqui "dispara" as teclas sobre algum elemento
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Vou testar aqui mano, obrigado.

Comment: Não conhecia esse comando

Comment: É bem interessante, eu já utilizei para disparar o CTRL + D para adicionar um link aos favoritos do navegador.

Comment: Seria isso @Ricardo `$(function(){
     $("#btnClick").click(function(){
      var press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
   press.which = 78;  // tecla n
   press.shiftKey = true;  // shift pressionado
   press.altKey = true;  // alt pressionado
   $(this).trigger(press);  // aqui "dispara" as teclas sobre algum elemento
     });

 });`